# Can't see Multibranch job type in new job screen

Tags: jenkins

I install new jenkins server version 2.9
I install All pipline plugins on it include multibranch.
But i can't see Multibranch job type in new job screen

Can you Pleae help?

Comment: make sure you've installed `Pipeline: Multibranch`

Comment: Thanks, I install the latest version of Pipeline: Multibranch. But still can't see it